# Difference between an exact and Big O Notation for worst case runtime

Tags: algorithms, runtime-analysis, big-o-notation

I'm having a problem with an exercise, I'm supposed to calculate the *exact* worst case runtime    and the worst case runtime in *Big O Notation* for a given algorithm.

This is what I'm struggling to understand, I think I know how to recognize what's the runtime using the big O Notation as it's only a nested loop but what is exactly an *exact* runtime?

How am I supposed to calculate it?
How would that look like with a simple bubble sort algorithm?

Comment: What did the person who gave you the exercise say when you asked them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the bubble sort algorithm shown below:

```
function sort(A)
    n = A.length
    for i = 1 to n-1
        for j = n downto i+1
            if A[j] < A[j-1]
                swap A[j] with A[j-1]
```

One way to measure the performance of this algorithm is to count the number of swaps performed by the algorithm.  For the worst-case input, the number of swaps performed by the algorithm is $(n-1)+(n-2)+\cdots+2+1 = n(n-1)/2$.  This is the exact number of swaps performed in the worst-case.

In the worst case, the number of swaps performed by the algorithm is $O(n^2)$. This expression uses asymptotic notation to describe the worst-case performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t calculate any runtime except for some very simple model of a CPU. You can calculate the exact number of comparisons, or the exact number of operations moving array elements of a particular implementation of an algorithm, but it’s practically impossible to predict how many seconds or microseconds the algorithm will run for.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing precise was specified, you can enumerate all operations by type, such as addition, comparison, swap... and give a detailed account of their numbers. That assumes the the basic operations take some constant (but unknown) time each.

In practice, you prefer to limit the evaluation to a single type of operation, such that the other operations are performed in at most a proportional amount.